# creating custom search filter for filtering data

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

I want to send custom filter string/json in filtering request to server. But cant find a way to achieve this

Below is the filter footer added to the filter dialog

```
customFilterDialogFooter: (currentFilterList, applyNewFilters) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: "40px" }}>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        onClick={() => handleFilterSubmit(applyNewFilters)}
      >
        Apply Filters
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and using following function grid options function

```
 onFilterConfirm: (filterList) => {
  // setGridProps((prevState) => ({
  //   ...prevState,
  //   pageNum: 0,
  //   query: filtering,
  // }));

  console.log(filtering);
},
onFilterChange: (column, filterList, type) => {
  if (column.filter === true) {
    let colIndex = columns.findIndex(function (item, i) {
      return item.name === column.name;
    });
    filtering[column.name] = filterList[colIndex][0];
  }
}
```

where as filtering is an object initialize with empty object. But the issue is handleFilterSubmit is called before onFilterChange is invoked . So the question is is there any other function available or is there any way that i can create my filtering object.